# Performance difference between `is` and `as` in LINQ

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have two versions of a LINQ selector which does some filtering of non-generic types and returns a generic enumeration. Consider we will fully enumerate both with the same parameter `source`, I wonder what version will be more performant:

```
public static IEnumerable<ICollection<TData>> OfType1<TData>(this IEnumerable<ICollection> source) =>
    source
        .Select(c => c as ICollection<TData>)
        .Where(c => !(c is null));

public static IEnumerable<ICollection<TData>> OfType2<TData>(this IEnumerable<ICollection> source) =>
    source
        .Where(c => c is ICollection<TData>)
        .Select(c => c as ICollection<TData>);
```

In my believe it all boils down to the difference between `is` and `as` since in `OfType2` we filter first (not last) and thus can possible do less of the second operator. In the first case, we need to do both operations on all elements in the enumerable.

**So what actually does perform best here? And how do `is` and `as` differ under the hood? (Links to source code welcome!)**

Comment: Why not measure yourself on your data?

Comment: `is` and `as` together are basically two casts, so my guess is that the second version will be slower. However, you should always simply try it and see.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet

Comment: And why not just use Linq's `OfType`? `source.OfType<TData>().ToList()`?

Comment: both seem equally inefficient and pointless compared to `=> source.OfType<ICollection<TData>>();`. LINQ is usually few times slower than regular loops, and the difference of `as`/`is` is pretty small compared to that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You really need to test this yourself as implementations may change.

However, your current approach is a bit wasteful. `OfType` will be more performant, more direct and less allocations.

As you can see from the implementation it is just using `is` and `yield` which is kind of the spirit of your extension method anyway

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> OfType<TResult>(this IEnumerable source) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    return OfTypeIterator<TResult>(source);
}
static IEnumerable<TResult> OfTypeIterator<TResult>(IEnumerable source) {
    foreach (object obj in source) {
        if (obj is TResult) yield return (TResult)obj;
    }
}
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[Enumerable.OfType(IEnumerable) Method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,d25cf953c577dcd6)

> Filters the elements of an IEnumerable based on a specified type.

[OfType Source Code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,d25cf953c577dcd6)

[Benchmark.Net](http://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet)

Comment: What implementation can change?

Comment: @abatishchev it was a reference to the framework and clr, the main point is to just test this stuff for your self as the performance difference and optimisations may vary in the future (in general)